# Detect text filled by barcode scanner(reader) javascript

Tags: javascript, input

The code checks barcodes using a barcode scanner.
`Search_code` is filled by a user (keyboard) , and `insert_code` is filled automatically by a barcode scanner.
Currently, code works if both inputs are introduced in barcode scanner values ​​which is not functional for me.

The code needs to run when:

1. `search_code` is entered manually ( keyboard ) and
2. `insert_code` is filled automatically by the barcode scanner

```js
var search_code = document.getElementById('search_code');
var insert_code = document.getElementById('insert_code');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var audio = new Audio('sound.wav');


// respond to button click
button.onclick = function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 

  // show verification result:
  if (search_code.value == insert_code.value) {
    result.textContent = 'code ok';
    result.className = "ok";
    audio.play();
  } else {
    result.textContent = 'code is not ok';
    result.className = "not-ok";
  }
  // clear input when wrong:
  if (search_code.value !== insert_code.value) {
    insert_code.value = '';
  }
  return false;
};

function clearField(input) {
  input.value = "";
};
```

```html
....     
<form>
        <input type="text" name="search_code" onfocus="clearField(this, this.placeholder='');" onblur="this.placeholder='introdu codul'" id="search_code" placeholder="introdu codul" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br/>
        <input type="" name="insert_code" onfocus="clearField(this, this.placeholder='');" onblur="this.placeholder='scaneaza codul'" id="insert_code" placeholder="scaneaza codul" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="verifica COD" />
    </form>

    </div>
  <div id="result"></div>
   </div>
   <script src="js/action_input.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: If it is failing on the typed entry, `search_code.value == insert_code.value; // false` .. so how exactly are they different? You may want to remove characters like whitespace and make everything upper case before testing

Comment: The code only works if in the search_code I insert values by barcode scanner and when i enter values manually (keyboard) i have to be pressed the button. Which are the steps: 1. I click on `search_code`, write code input from the keyboard 2. Press the button; 3. click on `insert_code` input; 4. Press the button on the barcode scanner. I want to remove step 2, not to be required to press the button every time.

Comment: Do you have an actual question or do you want to [hire a developer](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent a `textbox` from being filled by a bar-code reader simply disable `onpaste` event .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#search_code').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow and I don't know all the rules. To transform input in uppercase, I have to ask another question or can I continue here.

Comment: First you should search for your question and if It does not exist on stackoverflow you can(have to) ask another question.

In your case I'm sure that the questions does exist.